# How to Upload fixed width length value using pgloader?

Tags: linux, postgresql, psql, pgadmin-4

How to use pgloader in postgres/pgadmin platform?
How can I upload fixed width length column value from text file?

Example:

```
**column_name position length**
given_name     1       20
mobile         22      15
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did in a hurry, using the table.load file:

```
   LOAD FIXED FROM stdin
       WITH ENCODING utf8
             (
                 given_name     from 0 for 20
               , mobile         from 21 for 15
             )
        INTO postgresql://user:pwd@host:port/database?schema.table
             (
  given_name     
, mobile         
);
```

Using the command:

```
cat yourfile.txt | pgloader table.load
```

I got it loaded.

Regards